# Trying to create a table from line data in a dual axis spatial sheet

Tags: tableau-desktop

I want to create a table showing ONLY lines that cross over 2 Regions. For example ES02 - ES03 has 2 lines crossing over the borders and those lines have data in a table. I want to create a table that would have the 2 regions and the param data listed.

Not all lines cross over 2 borders so i can just use the csv.

I'm doing it for Europe but I zoomed in for an example.

[Example 1a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pkfyu.png)

[Exmaple 1b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WD2g.png)

[Example 1c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkHQq.png)

I was expecting a table similar to the format.

| Regions       | Data 1                  | Data 2   |

| ES01 - ES02   | Param data for line 1   |    --    |

| ES01 - PT01   | Param data for line 1   |   --     |

| ES02 - ES03   | Param data for line 1   | Param data for line 2

TWBX https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ahc-UP5Eu3jJk-V-rkcWK426OoKrWA?e=YeMuMV